# Using Multiple Threads to write in single file

Tags: java, io, random-access

> Can i use multiple threads to write in **RandomAccessFile** in Java ?
>
> I know RandomAccessFiles allows to read & write at any position.
>
> I want to create n portions of above File and let each thread to write
>   contents in a particular portion.
>
> will it improve IO performance?

**Eager to hear soon......**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open the file twice with the proper sharing specified, having two RandomAccessFile objects pointing to the same file. The OS will manage properly if you're careful not to write and read the same location twice (the OS will handle it then, too, but you'll get unexpected results).

However, it will not improve your I/O performance - CPU is almost never the bottleneck when it comes to I/O. What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to download a file from URL, for this I want 2 threads to run concurrently to read in buffer & write to RandomAccessFile simultaneously. Hope it would enhance downloading speed for my downloader

Comment: Alternatively, you could have each thread stream to a temporary file (safer), then when all threads are finished reconstruct the original file. May or may not be simpler, probably no difference in performance, but with less concurrency headaches.

Comment: Nice Comment AlistairIsrael, but are you really sure that it won't help in improving IO performance.

Comment: The individual threads should largely be gated by the network I/O throughput, not disk I/O. On top of that, depending upon how large the complete file is, the time it'll take to reconstruct the original file from its constituent parts may increase the total download time.

Comment: Your network is a lot slower than your disk I/O (unless you're downloading the file from a server connected to your computer with a 10Gb network). Don't bother with optimizing the disk access. If you want to increase download throughput, try opening two connections to the server (as download accelerators sometimes do).